# Serial.println() affects Serial1 readings

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having trouble converting some C++ code to Arduino. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have successfully done the above. However the only problem now is that the Arduino code I have reads the voltage accurately and properly but no other register. I can write the throttle too. If I call a different amount of `Serial.println()` statements, the readings on the other registers change and in some cases the voltage register stops working too.This is found in my code when I do

```
Serial.print("Voltage: );
```

If I printed out all of these registers the answers change. I can't figure out why this happens.

```
/* DEFINITIONS */
#include <math.h>

/* FLOATS */

uint8_t command[5];
uint8_t response[3];

/* INTEGERS */
byte deviceId = 0x17;
double throttleOut = 0;
double voltage = 0;
double rippleVoltage = 0;
double current = 0;
double power = 0;
double throttle = 0;
double pwm = 0;
double rpm = 0;
double temp = 0;
double becVoltage = 0;
double safeState = 0;
double linkLiveEnabled = 0;
double eStopStatus = 0;
double rawNTC = 0;

/* SETUP */
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);

}
void loop() {
  flushPort();
  ReadWriteRegister(128, 1000, true);//_throttleOut is 0[0%] to 65535[100%]
  voltage = ReadWriteRegister(0, 0, false) / 2042.0 / 0.05;
  rippleVoltage = ReadWriteRegister(1, 0, false) / 2042 / 0.25;
  current = ReadWriteRegister(2, 0, false) / 204200 * 50;
  power = voltage * current;
  throttle = (ReadWriteRegister(3, 0, false) / 2042.0 / 1.0);
  pwm = ReadWriteRegister(4, 0, false) / 2042.0 / 3.996735;
  rpm = ReadWriteRegister(5, 0, false) / 2042.0 / 4.89796E-5;
  int poleCount = 20;//Motor pole count
  rpm = rpm / (poleCount / 2);
  temp = ReadWriteRegister(6, 0, false) / 2042.0 * 30.0;
  becVoltage = ReadWriteRegister(7, 0, false) / 2042 / 0.25;
  safeState = ReadWriteRegister(26, 0, false);
  linkLiveEnabled = ReadWriteRegister(25, 0, false);
  eStopStatus = ReadWriteRegister(27, 0, false) == 0 ? false : true;
  rawNTC = ReadWriteRegister(9, 0, false) / 2042.0 / 0.01567091;
  rawNTC = 1.0 / (log(rawNTC * 10200.0 / (255.0 - rawNTC) / 10000.0 ) / 3455.0 + 1.0 / 298.0) - 273.0;
  Serial.print("Voltage: ");
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Serial.print("Current: ");
  Serial.println(current);
}
void flushPort() {

  command[0] = command[1] = command[2] = command[3] = command[4] = 0;
Serial1.write(command, 5);
  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    Serial1.read();
  }
}
double ReadWriteRegister(int reg, int value, bool writeMode) {
  // Send read command

  command[0] = (byte)(0x80 | deviceId);
  command[1] = (byte)reg;
  command[2] = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
  command[3] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
  command[4] = (byte)(0 - command[0] - command[1] - command[2] - command[3]);
  Serial1.write(command, 5);


  // Read response
  if(Serial1.available() == 3) {
  response[0] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  response[1] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  response[2] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  }

  if ((byte)(response[0] + response[1] + response[2]) == 0)
  {
    return (double)((response[0] << 8) + (response[1]));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error communicating with device!");
  }
}
```

***EDIT 2***
Some photos of a usb logic analyzer shots.
    [[image: 1]]
    [[image: 2]]
    [[image: 3]]
    [[image: 4]]
    [[image: 5]]
    [[image: 6]]
    [[image: 7]]
And all of the packets together in this one:
[[image: All of them]]
Maybe this will help with timeouts etc. It's all the info I have :.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please tell us what the problem actually *is*? What is the problem with the second code snippet? Doesn't it work? Do you get build errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected results? Something else? Please elaborate!

Comment: Sorry you're right. I've never programmed with C# or C++ before, only Arduino and I knew Arduino was a variant so I assumed it was C++ when it looked fairly similar. Rookie mistake :\. The code I posted below does compile, however it doesn't work. The device doesn't have the same response as the first code. If you'd like, I could post the full snippet and then my Arduino code so you could get a look at the bigger picture?

Comment: That should work. Does the device drop bytes that aren't part of the package ? (Just in case there's some noise).

Comment: The code above didn't work however I will update the code soon as I have worked on it since. The device won't drop any other bytes.

Comment: I've tried sending some test data using an Arduino like so: ```char command[5];

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  int deviceId = 1;
  int value = 300;
  int reg = 23;

  command[0] = (0x80 | deviceId);
  command[1] = reg;
  command[2] = highByte(value);
  command[3] = lowByte(value);
  command[4] = (0 - command[0] - command[1] - command[2] - command[3]);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.write(command);
  delay(5000);
}```. Using [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/), I [see some extra bytes](http://lifesine.eu/so/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-19%20at%2017.02.25.png). Strange.

Comment: I've updated my entire question. After managing to get the registers to work (but only one) I get weird readings in the other registers and they are affected by the amount of Serial.println statements that I do. This is so weird since this should by no way effect the readings of the registers. The voltage register works consistently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way that `ReadWriteRegister` will work.  At 115200, each character takes about 87us to be sent or received.  In that time, the Arduino can execute about 100 lines of code!

Look at this snippet:

```
  Serial1.write(command, 5);

  // Read response
  if(Serial1.available() == 3) {
```

The `write` function only puts the command in the output buffer and starts sending the first character.  It returns *before* all the characters have been transmitted.  That will take 500us!

Then, you look to see if there a 3-character response has been received.  But the command hasn't finished being transmitted, and you certainly didn't wait 258us (3 times 86us).  It could even take longer if the device needs time to execute your command.

You have to do two things: wait for the command to be sent, and wait for the response to be received.  Try this:

```
  Serial1.write(command, 5);
  Serial1.flush(); // wait for command to go out

  // Wait for response to come back
  while (Serial1.available() < 3)
    ; // waitin'....

  // Read response
  response[0] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  response[1] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  response[2] = (byte)Serial1.read();
```

This is called "blocking", because the Arduino won't do anything else while you're waiting for the response.

However, if a character is missed, your program could "hang" there, waiting for a 4th character if the 2nd character is not sent/received correctly (it happens).  So you should put a 500us timeout in that while loop:

```
  // Wait for response
  uint32_t startTime = micros();
  while ((Serial1.available() < 3) && (micros() - startTime < 500UL))
    ; // waitin'...
```

... or longer, if you know how quickly the device will respond.  Then you can determine whether you actually got a response:

#### UPDATED with complete program (v2):

```
/* DEFINITIONS */
#include <math.h>

/* INTEGERS */

byte deviceId = 0x17;
uint8_t command[5];
uint8_t response[3];

/* FLOATS */

double  throttleOut     = 0.0;
double  voltage         = 0.0;
double  rippleVoltage   = 0.0;
double  current         = 0.0;
double  power           = 0.0;
double  throttle        = 0.0;
double  pwm             = 0.0;
double  rpm             = 0.0;
double  temp            = 0.0;
double  becVoltage      = 0.0;
uint8_t safeState       = 0;
uint8_t linkLiveEnabled = 0;
bool    eStopStatus     = 0;
double  rawNTC          = 0.0;

/* SETUP */
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println( F("---------------------------") );

  // According to the spec, you can synchronize with the device by writing
  // five zeroes.  Although I suspect this is mostly for the SPI and I2c
  // interfaces (not TTL-level RS-232), it won't hurt to do it here.
  Serial1.write( command, 5 );
  delay( 250 ); // ms
  while (Serial1.available())
    Serial1.read(); // throw away

  // Set the throttle just once
  ReadWriteRegister(128, 1000);//_throttleOut is 0[0%] to 65535[100%]
}

//  For 12-bit A/D conversions, the range is 0..4096.  Values at
//  the top and bottom are usually useless, so the value is limited
//  to 6..4090 and then shifted down to 0..4084.  The middle of this
//  range will be the "1.0" value: 2042.  Depending on what is being 
//  measured, you still need to scale the result.
const double ADC_FACTOR = 2042.0;

void loop() {

  uint32_t scanTime = millis(); // mark time now so we can delay later

  voltage             = ReadWriteRegister(  0, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 20.0;
  rippleVoltage       = ReadWriteRegister(  1, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 4.0;
  current             = ReadWriteRegister(  2, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 50.0;
  power               = voltage * current;
  throttle            = ReadWriteRegister(  3, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 1.0;
  pwm                 = ReadWriteRegister(  4, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 0.2502;
  rpm                 = ReadWriteRegister(  5, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 20416.66;
  const int poleCount = 20;//Motor pole count
  rpm                 = rpm / (poleCount / 2);
  temp                = ReadWriteRegister(  6, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 30.0;
  becVoltage          = ReadWriteRegister(  7, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 4.0;
  safeState           = ReadWriteRegister( 26, 0 );
  linkLiveEnabled     = ReadWriteRegister( 25, 0 );
  eStopStatus         = ReadWriteRegister( 27, 0 );
  rawNTC              = ReadWriteRegister(  9, 0 ) / ADC_FACTOR * 63.1825;

  const double R0 =  1000.0;
  const double R2 = 10200.0;
  const double B  =  3455.0;
  rawNTC          = 1.0 / (log(rawNTC * R2 / (255.0 - rawNTC) / R0 ) / B + 1.0 / 298.0) - 273.0;

  Serial.print( F("Voltage: ") );
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Serial.print( F("Current: ") );
  Serial.println(current);
  Serial.print( F("Throttle: ") );
  Serial.println(throttle);
  Serial.print( F("RPM: ") );
  Serial.println(rpm);

  // These prints do not actually send the characters, they only queue
  // them up to be sent gradually, at 115200.  The characters will be
  // pulled from the output queue by a TX interrupt, and given to the
  // UART one at a time.
  //
  // To prevent these interrupts from possibly interfering with any other
  // timing, and to pace your program, we will wait *now* for all the
  // characters to be sent to the Serial Monitor.
  Serial.flush();

  // Let's pace things a little bit more for testing: delay here until
  // it's time to scan again.
  const uint32_t SCAN_INTERVAL = 1000UL; // ms
  while (millis() - scanTime < SCAN_INTERVAL)
    ; // waitin'
}

int16_t ReadWriteRegister(int reg, int value) {
  // Flush input, as suggested by Gee Bee
  while (Serial1.available() > 0)
    Serial1.read();

  // Send command (register number determines whether it is read or write)

  command[0] = (byte)(0x80 | deviceId);
  command[1] = (byte)reg;
  command[2] = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
  command[3] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
  command[4] = (byte)(0 - command[0] - command[1] - command[2] - command[3]);
  Serial1.write(command, 5);

  // The command bytes are only queued for transmission, they have not
  // actually gone out.  You can either wait for command to go out
  // with a `Serial1.flush()`  *OR*  add the transmission time to the
  // timeout value below.  However, if anything else has queued bytes
  // to be sent and didn't wait for them to go out, the calculated 
  // timeout would be wrong.  It is safer to flush now and guarantee
  // that *all* bytes have been sent: anything sent earlier (I don't 
  // see anything else, but you may change that later) *plus* 
  // these 5 command bytes.

  Serial1.flush();

  // Now wait for response to come back, for a certain number of us
  //   The TIMEOUT could be as short as 3 character times @ the Serial1
  //   baudrate: 3 * (10 bits/char) / 115200bps = 261us.  This is if
  //   the device responds immediately.  Gee Bee says 20ms, which would 
  //   be 20000UL.  There's nothing in the spec, but 1ms seems generous
  //   for reading the raw NTC value, which may require an ADC conversion.
  //   Even the Arduino can do that in 100us.  Try longer if you get
  //   timeout warnings.

  const uint32_t TIMEOUT = 2000UL;

  uint32_t startTime = micros();
  while ((Serial1.available() < 3) && (micros() - startTime < TIMEOUT))
    ; // waitin'...

  int16_t result;

  if (Serial1.available() >= 3) {
    response[0] = (byte)Serial1.read();
    response[1] = (byte)Serial1.read();
    response[2] = (byte)Serial1.read();

    // Verify the checksum
    if (response[0] + response[1] + response[2] != 0) {
      Serial.print( reg );
      Serial.println( F(" Checksum error!") );
      Serial.flush(); // optional, use it for now to stay synchronous
    }

    //  Cast to 16 bits *first*, then shift and add
    result = (((int16_t) response[0]) << 8) + (int16_t) response[1];

  } else {
    //  Must have timed out, because there aren't enough characters
    Serial.print( reg );
    Serial.println( F(" Timed out!") );
    Serial.flush(); // optional, use it for now to stay synchronous

    result = 0;
  }

  return result; // You must always return something
}
```

Comments:

- There was an error in your result calculation that is (probably) fixed in the answer above.  Casting to `double` outside the addition caused you to lose the top 8 bits, I think.  Calculating as above should give the correct answer.
- After a little googling, I see this is for a [Castle Serial Link controller](http://www.castlecreations.com/support/documents/castle_serial_link_v1.3.pdf).  That would have been useful to know.  It describes the checksum, which I used in the `ReadWriteRegister` function above.  The function can tell you if it timed out or if the checksum was wrong.  This would also imply that longer timeouts may be required.  It's not clear if your device waits up to 480ms to get the latest value, or if it is continuously cacheing them and responds immediately with the last value recevied from the ESC.  *Writes*, however, will not be reflected in the read values for up to 480ms, because of the time it takes the ESC to receive a command and then send the new values.  See [ESC Castle Link protocol](http://www.castlecreations.com/support/documents/castle_link_live_2.0.pdf).
- The `ReadWriteRegister` function returns a 16-bit integer, which will be more efficient.  Comparing floating-point numbers is never good.  BTW, `double` is just single `float` on the 8-bit Arduinos.
- The `ReadWriteRegister` function doesn't need the `writemode` argument, because the register number determines whether you are writing or reading the device.
- Writing the `throttle` value is only performed in setup.

---

#### UPDATE 2

Your **L**ogic **A**nalyzer shots appear to show a "scan" for ESCs.  It is trying each device ID, and some of them reply with a non-zero voltage.  Also, it appears to be running at 9600, **NOT** 115200.  Is this from a different setup?

Regardless, it confirms what the controller spec said: write 5 bytes, read 3.  The checksum values are as expected.  However, it is running 10 times slower than your program, so it doesn't provide much new information regarding timeouts.  It may imply there *is* a small delay before the device responds, perhaps ~1 bit time, or about 100us.

Have you read the controller spec?  You should compare the program to the spec to make sure you understand how the controller works.

I have modified the program above to:

- sync with the controller in `setup` (write 5 zero bytes and wait 250ms),
- use scaling numbers from the spec (instead of their reciprocals?),
- use meaningful constants instead of "magic" numbers (e.g. 2042),
- use integer or boolean types for a few registers instead of `double` (see `safeState`, `linkLiveStatus`, and `eStopStatus`),
- increase the timeout to 2ms (keep increasing it if you continue to get frequent timeouts), and
- output the `reg` number when an error occurs.

If you want to be successful in this area, you must learn to read a specification and translate its requirements into code that *conforms*.  The program you started with is non-conformal at worst, or misleading at best.  I am particularly amused by the comments that say "INTEGERS" and "FLOATS", yet those sections contain the opposite.

Perhaps this is a lesson in fixing someone else's code?  It truly has many problems that you will encounter.  If I had a nickel for every time I said:

- "What's that number for?"
- "That comment is wrong!"
- "The spec says you're supposed to..."
- "Why is this so hard to read?  I'll just add some spacing."

...I would be a very rich man.  :)

(end of updates)

---

#### P.S.

This also matches the symptoms you describe:  Because you didn't wait for the transmission to complete, 0 bytes are read the first time through (`read` will return a -1 or 0xFF byte).

After you've called this routine several times (and queued up several command into the output buffer), 500us have elapsed and the first command has finally been sent.  The device responds by starting to send 3 characters.  87us later, the Arduino has finally received the first character.  It gets read by *one* of your `read` statements, but who knows which one?  It will be random, based on the elapsed time.

More commands get sent, and individual characters are received and read by one of those statements, until 64 bytes of commands **OR Serial.println chars** are queued up.  Then the `write` command **OR Serial.print** blocks until the output has room for the newest command.  (This addresses the title of your question.)

When enough command bytes or debug message chars are finally transmitted, the `Serial1.write` or `Serial.print` returns.  In the meantime, received characters are going into the input buffer.  (That's where they are stored until you call `read`.)

At this point, three `read` statements in a row will actually get characters that the device sent.  But because of the random consumption of characters earlier, it could be the last character of one response, followed by the first two characters of the next response.  You're "out-of-sync" with the 3-byte responses.

To stay "in synch" with the device, you have to wait for the send to complete with `flush`, and wait for the response to come back with `while`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tried it and it didn't work. However I did play around and I found that with the very basic code I had before I can call one register and it will work reliably and very quickly. If I call any register after that (like I was calling all of them) the other ones do not work. I've tried adding flushPort() after every time I call a register but that stops anything from working. Also the Serial1.flush() seems to stop it from working too. :\

Comment: Uh, `flushPort` shouldn't write anything.  That will just stack up more chars in the output buffer.  It's ok to flush the input as suggested by @GeeBee (*that's* attribution), but don't write anything.  Your question still shows doing the write and then immediately checking for 3 availabe to read.  That will never work.  You **have** to wait for the command to go out, and then you **have** to wait long enough for the chars to come back.  I will expand my answer to the complete program.

Comment: @Peter, updated with full program above.  Be sure to read the comments in and after the code.

Comment: Thank you for all of this effort!! I haven't tried the complete code yet (I just arrived at school) but I'll try it when I get home. Hopefully it will work well :). Thanks for all of the effort.

Comment: I just got home and tried it. I had to change the timeout to more like 1000UL. However it worked but unreliably. At first it took me some time before anything worked after adjusting the timeout. I got the voltage, current, rpm and throttle but the others say checksum error. When they say timeout, the voltage, current, rpm and throttle give 0. When the throttle is working, which requires me to unplug the device then plug it back in without powering off the controller it just provides a timeout and zeroes for voltage, current, throttle and rpm. :\ It seems very close though!

Comment: If it helps I have a number of screenshots of a usb logic analyzer on this protocol. I'll put them in an update in the question.

Comment: @Peter, "UPDATE 2" section added and program modified above.

Comment: Thank you for all of this effort. I can't say enough how grateful I am. I saw checksum errors when I tried this code, but I ended up printing out all of the registers, and commenting out the Serial.println parts of the verify checksum code and they all worked perfectly. Thank you for all of this help - it finally works!! It's taken years to get to this! Thank you!

Comment: I know I suck at explaining myself :). And I make silly mistakes like putting non-integers in a clearly labeled integer section :\ but I love learning from it. Thanks for your persistence and help, it's become a very large answer. I've learned quite a lot about Arduino from this, especially the timing of it all. Cannot thank you enough. I'm pretty happy right now.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but this code has some issues. You assume that

- No trash is getting received while your code runs
- The hardware connected to Serial1 answers 3 bytes in 0.00ns

Use the following pattern in ReadWriteRegister:

- discard any pending input from Serial1
- send out the command
- wait until *at least* 3 bytes have been received, or some resonable timeout occurs (see slash-dev's detailed answer)
- read 3 bytes (if there was something received)

In the code:

```
double ReadWriteRegister(int reg, int value, bool writeMode) {
  // Send read command

  command[0] = (byte)(0x80 | deviceId);
  command[1] = (byte)reg;
  command[2] = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
  command[3] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
  command[4] = (byte)(0 - command[0] - command[1] - command[2] - command[3]);

  // discard any input
  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    Serial1.read();
  }

  // write out command
  Serial1.write(command, 5);

  // wait for 3 bytes
  uint32_t startTime = micros();
  while ((Serial1.available() < 3) && (micros() - startTime < 20000UL))
    ; // waiting for 20 ms for the answer

  // Read response
  if(Serial1.available() >= 3) {  // >=3 accept also more bytes
      response[0] = (byte)Serial1.read();
      response[1] = (byte)Serial1.read();
      response[2] = (byte)Serial1.read();
  }

  if ((byte)(response[0] + response[1] + response[2]) == 0)
  {
    return (double)((response[0] << 8) + (response[1]));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error communicating with device!");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You copied my code into your answer?  Honestly!  This code has some issues: (1) no return value for `else` clause at end; (2) you should call `flush` after `write` to make sure no other commands are queued up.  The "discard input" at the beginning isn't a bad idea, but it doesn't guarantee you're in sync yet.

Comment: Good catch, I've added the missing return statement (that was missing from the original code, but not relevant for the issue!)

Comment: I found no necessity to use flush(). Arduino (we dunno which one, but usually) comes with a 2 bytes of send "buffer", and the data is getting getting written nicely anyhow. We don't need to wait until the last bit is sent (flush would do that), since we're continuing with some more wait.
Probably it makes sense to increase the timeout to 20 milliseconds or so, in order to allow the other hardware to answer.

Comment: Your code is very well addressing one half of the issues. 
I found nothing bad including that, and referring your answer in my comment. 

Consume incoming trash before starting a transaction, and probably a bit longer timeout is all what shall be added.